# Finitely presented monoid with non-solvable word problem

Tags: monoid, group-presentation, combinatorics-on-words

A. Markoff ([On the impossibility of certain algorithms in the theory of associative systems](http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayAbstract?fromPage=online&aid=9100406&fileId=S0022481200074545)) and E. Post ([Recursive Unsolvability of a Problem of Thue](https://www.wolframscience.com/prizes/tm23/images/Post2.pdf)) provide examples of a finitely presented monoid with non-solvable word problem — or at least, so I read in [various](http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~mkambites/events/bmc2008/kambites.pdf) [sources](http://www-groups.mcs.st-andrews.ac.uk/~alanc/pub/cm_decfpor.pdf). I do not have access to any copy of Markoff's paper, and Post's (accessible via link above) is so verbose in his description that I cannot discern the actual presentation of the monoid in question.

Could someone provide a presentation in "modern notation" of such a monoid? e.g., $\langle a,b | a^3=b^3\rangle$. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The group with 10 generators $\{a,b,c,d,e,p,q,r,t,k\}$ and the following 27 relations has an unsolvable word problem:

\begin{align}
p^{10}a &= ap \\\
p^{10}b &= bp \\\
p^{10}c &= cp \\\
p^{10}d &= dp \\\
p^{10}e &= ep \\\
aq^{10} &= qa \\\
bq^{10} &=qb \\\
cq^{10} &= qc \\\
dq^{10} &= qd \\\
eq^{10} &= qe \\\
ra &= ar \\\
rb &= br \\\
rc &= cr \\\
rd &= dr \\\
re &= er \\\
pacqr &= rpcaq \\\
p^2adq^2r &= rp^2daq^2 \\\
p^3bcq^3r &= rp^3cbq^3 \\\
p^4bdq^4r &= rp^4dbq^4 \\\
p^5ceq^5r &= rp^5ecaq^5 \\\
p^6deq^6r &= rp^6edbq^6 \\\
p^7cdcq^7r &= rp^7cdceq^7 \\\
p^8ca^3q^8r &= rp^8a^3q^8 \\\
p^9da^3q^9r &= rp^9a^3q^9 \\\
pt &= tp \\\
qt &= tq \\\
a^{-3}ta^3k &= ka^{-3}ta^3
\end{align}

[It is given](http://shell.cas.usf.edu/~wclark/algctlg/groups.html) in D.J. Collins, *A simple presentation of a group with unsolvable word problem*.